# Novel where rationing is extended to time rationing

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

In that novel, a government managing a war economy tries to reduce further resource consumption by more rationing. In addition to food rationing already in place, they introduce time rationing: each month, people get a coupon book with the number of days they are allowed to have the next month. Workers and soldiers get 30 days, but artists e.g. will get no more than 10.

This starts making problems as man & wife don't necessarily have the same number of days, but also because a black market emerges with the well-off buying out enough coupons to live up to a few 100s of days a month.

I think it's a post-WWII novel, unsure whether it was written in English or maybe French. Covid lockdowns made it feel very contemporary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the answer to [A story about some people having more rationed days awake than others](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/223416/23243), [*La Carte* by Marcel Aymé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Carte) (reproduced in translation [here](http://www.stresscafe.com/translations/ayme/aymehome.html))

Google translated summary from the French Wikipedia page:

> The news is written in the form of a diary, that of a writer who discovers with amazement that from now on, according to a government decree, the time of life will be rationed to save food. Each category of population is allocated a certain number of days per month according to its degree of usefulness; citizens deemed unworthy of normal life receive a card with coupons, one per day of life. The old men have only one week, the artists two, to the great scandal of the writer. Very quickly, a traffic of coupons is organized, (allusion to the black market of the foodstuffs which prevailed under the occupation), in detriment of the poorest; some very wealthy people are beginning to be able to live more than thirty days a month.

As you note, it was originally in French. 1942 is a bit before the end of the war, but the translation wasn't until later.